# Limit string from another string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have

```
char filemem[14], *file, *path;
file = strcpy(filemem,"/path/to/file");
path = file - 4;
```

I want to have `char *path = file - 4` such that `char *path` only reads `/path/to/`. Is it possible to show part of the pointer with out having to create a copy of the string into another memory

Comment: `char *file = /path/to/file;` isn't valid C code.

Comment: If you can modify the string you can assign a null byte to the location after `/path/to/`

Comment: No, that is not possible, if you want both strings to be valid or if the string is no modifyable (e.g. a string literal).

Comment: Consider keeping the folder path separately in the first place.

Comment: @scotthunter I'm aware I just assumed I was getting my message across

Comment: You should edit your question to contain valid `C` code, otherwise your objective is confusing

Comment: any thoughts on the update

Comment: Yes, it relies on knowing the max length of the file name. And `strcpy` returns the destination pointer, so `path = file - 4;` (which is `filemem - 4`) isn't useful.

Comment: Ah so I will just have to create another memory for it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, strings are always terminated by the NUL byte (`'\0'`).

`char *path = file - 4` would point to an address four bytes in front of the `file` pointer. It does not mean "truncate the string by four bytes".

In order to truncate a string, you must place a NUL byte one past your desired final character. If your string is read-only, you must have additional memory to copy the desired characters over. There is no way to have a slice of a C string that ends before the NUL terminating byte, and still have it be valid for functions that expect a NUL terminated string.

Some examples:

Modifying the existing string:

```
int main(void) {
    char file[] = "/path/to/file";
    strrchr(file, '/')[1] = '\0';

    puts(file);
}
```

Copying a substring from read-only memory:

```
char *repath(const char *path) {
    size_t len = strrchr(path, '/') - path + 1;
    return strncpy(calloc(len + 1, 1), path, len);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *file = "/path/to/file";
    char *fileless = repath(file);

    puts(fileless);
    free(fileless);
}
```

*(Error handling omitted in both examples for brevity. `strrchr` and `calloc` can return NULL.)*

Answer (score 0):

If by "show" you mean printing, you can use `%.*s` as variable precision specifier when formatting the string with `printf` to truncate it:

```
    const char * path = "/path/to/file";
    int filename_offset = strrchr(path,'/') - path +1;
    
    printf("path     : %.*s\n", filename_offset, path);
    printf("filename : %s\n", path + filename_offset);
```

Output:

```
path     : /path/to/
filename : file
```